Make external links to Notion open new tabs
When I click a link to Notion content in some other application (say, a colleague emails me a link to a Notion page and I click it in Outlook), it pops up a new browser tab and then that redirects to viewing the Notion page in the Notion desktop app. That's all good, except that it opens the page on my last-used Notion tab, so I no longer have an open view of wherever that tab was pointing to previously. Can I reconfigure something so that the external link opens up the associated content on a brand-new Notion tab, without changing what's displayed on the Notion tabs I already had open?
In other words, I want it to work more like a typical web browser with regard to links opening as new tabs.

What's the Notion version? Works well for me. Try replacing https:// protocol with notion:// in the links, also

Notion version 3.17.0.  notion:// does not change the experience I see.  I'm on Windows 11 Enterprise, btw.
